# T- SQL Script For Finding Duplicate DisplayOrder And Assign Unique DisplayOrder

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am having a table With the following columns.

```
RouteID | StopID | DisplayOrder
  1         1         1
  2         2         1
  1         3         2
  2         4         1
```

Now due to some reason my DisplayOrder gets duplicated. I want to run the script that will find out the duplicate DisplayOrder records and change them with the next unique value.

I cannot set the DisplayOrder field with unique constraint as For different Route the stop's Display order column will have the same values.

Can any one provide me the script or best way to identify the Duplicate DisplayOrders for All the Routes and Update those duplicate values with next unique displayOrders for that route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't post what version of SQL Server you are running, but assuming you have access to the ROW_NUMBER() function, you ought to be able to do the following: note that this will update everything, not just the ones that are duplicated.  Let me know if that's a problem.

EDIT:

I've tweaked the script slightly to adjust for your desire not to affect the existing display order, but it still is going to set a new DisplayOrder value for every row.  Take a look at StopID #5 in my INSERT list below - I set it up to be greater than the previous values for RouteID #2, but it is only one higher.  If I do exactly what you want, and increment the DisplayOrder for either StopID #2 or #4, then I'll basically be creating a new duplicate, since now StopID #4 and StopID #5 share the same DisplayOrder of 2.

What I'm doing instead is updating every single record with a new display order value.  The `ORDER BY` clause within the `ROW_NUMBER()` function preserves the original DisplayOrder, so there won't be a change in functionality - but adding the StopID is going to help ensure that you consistently assign a unique value to each row.

```
-- Testing Data
DECLARE @StackOverflow TABLE (RouteID INT, StopID INT, DisplayOrder INT)
INSERT INTO @StackOverflow (RouteID, StopID, DisplayOrder) VALUES (1,1,1)
INSERT INTO @StackOverflow (RouteID, StopID, DisplayOrder) VALUES (2,2,1)
INSERT INTO @StackOverflow (RouteID, StopID, DisplayOrder) VALUES (1,3,2)
INSERT INTO @StackOverflow (RouteID, StopID, DisplayOrder) VALUES (2,4,1)
INSERT INTO @StackOverflow (RouteID, StopID, DisplayOrder) VALUES (2,5,2) -- this value is greater than a duplicated increment


-- Contains duplicated display order
SELECT * FROM @StackOverflow ORDER BY RouteID, DisplayOrder, StopID 

-- overwrite ALL display orders with a sequential display order, assuming that StopID is the correct sequence
UPDATE @StackOverflow 
SET DisplayOrder = s.RowNum
FROM 
    @StackOverflow so 
     INNER JOIN 
      (
        SELECT 
            StopID, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
                (PARTITION BY RouteID 
                ORDER BY 
                    DisplayOrder, -- adding this will preserve the existing display order
                    StopID -- this will rank the duplicates. 
                ) RowNum
        FROM @StackOverflow
      ) s ON 
        so.StopID = s.StopID

-- view final results
SELECT * FROM @StackOverflow ORDER BY RouteID, DisplayOrder, StopID
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try this out. One question : My requirement is this should not effect the existing DisplayOrders. I mean only duplicate displayOrders should be effected. I hope this script takes care of that right ?

Comment: @SachinTrivedi, I've updated my code a little bit, but I still think you'll need to update the existing DisplayOrders: after all, if you just add a value to the duplicated ones, you run the risk of creating a second duplicate if something already existed with the higher number.  My edit will preserve the functional order, even though it overwrites each row.  See the edited post for a full explanation, and let me know if that makes sense.